# AWS Lambda func "does not turn off"

Tags: lambda

I made lambda func Send Email with Attachment. Pretty simple function.

I send data (Json in Body) in Post request,
the lambda starts,
puts data in the email as an attachemnt
sends the email and
function is finished.

But unfortunately it is not like that.

If I run 3 requests one after the other within a few seconds of each other.
I get the first email with one attachment with data from body - let say it is ok.
I get another email with two attachments (one attachment with data from first request body, second attachment with data from second request body) - this is not OK
I get third email with three attachments - this is not OK
and so on

And after about 15-20 minutes I start Lambda again, then I get only one attachment.

I need one request one Email with one Attachemnt with data from body.

I feel like the function is not turning off or I don't know what is happening.

I am using serverless and function is define in yaml

Attachment:
timeout: 10
memorySize: 150
events:
- http:
path: Attachment
method: post
async: true
private: false
handler: api/Attachment/handler.handler
layers:
- { Ref: DalibsLambdaLayer }
package:
include:
- "./api/Attachemnt/**"
exclude:
- "**"

pls help

Comment: To be able to help you, can you post your code? Normally a Lambda is doing things exactly once. The second request/invocation normally does not know the other request/invocation. For me, this issue looks like you are requesting at least a second stateful service and your second/third invocation try to proceed something based on that.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I found the problem. I am using Nodemailer,  var attachemnts = []; was not inside of exports.handler = async (event, context) => { ... }. The state of attachemnts was saved somewhere.